# Событие, при котором выбрано 2 чекбокса

Tags: jquery, checkbox, булева-алгебра

```
    $('.col :checkbox').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {    
    if ($(this)[0].defaultValue === "cat" ) {
      alert('checked cat')
    }    
    if ($(this)[0].defaultValue === "hamster" ) {
      alert('checked hamster')
    }
    if ($(this)[0].defaultValue === "rat" ) {
      alert('checked rat')
    }

     if (($(this)[0].defaultValue === "rat" )
     && ($(this)[0].defaultValue === "dog" )) {
      alert('checked rat and dog')
    }    
  }
});
```

Срабатывает скрипт при выборе одного чекбокса. А как можно описать событие при выборе двух (и более)? Вот так не получается

```
if (($(this)[0].defaultValue === "rat" )
         && ($(this)[0].defaultValue === "dog" )) {
          alert('checked rat and dog')
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/5heo4az2

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.col :checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('.col').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1) {
    console.log("two or more checked");
  }
});
```